# Xcode autocomplete missing during string interpolation

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, string-interpolation

When using string interpolation, Xcode doesn't autocomplete variables unless the interpolation parenthesis and string are fully closed.

```
let myInt = 5  
print("My int is \(/*no auto complete here*/)  

print("My int is \()")  // then I can go back into \() and autocomplete works
```

This is somewhat frustrating and seemingly would be a very useful feature to have.  I was wondering if there's an option I'm missing to enable that.

Comment: no, this is how it's intended to be. String interpolation happens inside a string and before you close `"` it's not a `String`.

Comment: Sure, whatever it is, I think it would still be useful to allow autocompletion.  Doesn't seem like an impossible thing to do.